# How to use ELK with SCDF stream applications?

Tags: logstash, logback, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-config

In our company, we use `ELK` stack for logging through `Spring Cloud Config` and `logback`.
I would like to use ELK with `SCDF` too.

For our own applications, we can add the `logstash-logback-encoder` dependency to make it work.
But with standard `stream applications` which do not include this dependency, I have an exception because `LogstashTcpSocketAppender` is not defined ?

Is there a way to use ELK with stream applications like time-source or log-sink in ticktock stream for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option is to clone the repository, add the dependency and generate the applications on your own since it is considered as customization. Please let us know if you need help with generating the apps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I was afraid it would be this answer :)
Alternatively do you think it is possible to add the jar to the classpath with a configmap for example ?

Answer (score 0):

The generated apps are currently packaged into a Spring Boot executable jar using the default JarLauncher. They would instead need to use the [PropertiesLauncher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html#executable-jar.property-launcher) in order to support adding external dependencies like this. That being said, we are interested and exploring adding this ability to the generated apps. More details can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/issues/236).

For now, Soby's suggestion is the recommended approach.